# CSS Round Corner on Table Edges Issue in Document Mode IE7 Standards

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background-image

I got a simple question regarding the CSS background image.
My intention was using image to display round corner on table edges (without using border-radius property).

```
<style type="text/css">
    .top
    {
        background-repeat:repeat;
        vertical-align:top;
    }

    .left
    {
        text-align:left;
    }

    .middle
    {
    }

    .right
    {
        text-align:right;
    }

    .bottomLeft
    {
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }

    .bottom
    {
        background-repeat:repeat;
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }

    .bottomRight
    {
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }
</style>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="topLeft">
            <img height="16px" src="Images/greenTL.gif" style="vertical-align:bottom" />
        </td>
        <td class="top">
            <img height="4px" width="100%" src="Images/greenT.gif" style="vertical-align:8px" />
        </td>
        <td class="topRight">
            <img height="16px" src="Images/greenTR.gif" style="vertical-align:bottom" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">
            <img height="100%" src="Images/greenL.gif"/>
        </td>
        <td class="middle">
        </td>
        <td class="right">
            <img height="100%" src="Images/greenR.gif"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="bottomLeft">
            <img height="16px" src="Images/greenBL.gif" style="vertical-align:top" />
        </td>
        <td class="bottom" >
            <img height="4px" width="100%" src="Images/greenB.gif" />
        </td>
        <td class="bottomRight">
            <img height="16px" width="16px" src="Images/greenBR.gif" style="vertical-align:top"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The HTML & CSS above work perfectly fine in IE from Browser Mode 7 to 9, but it became distorted when changed **Document Mode to IE 7 Standard**.
It seem like having a gap between left and right vertical.

[image]

How can I solve the issue?
Before having CSS3 border-radius, what is the best approach to implement round corner in web page?

thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like http://css3pie.com/ which enables some CSS3 features on < IE9
versions. Personally, i'm one of those persons who think that web page shouldn't look 100% the same in all browsers e.g. Chrome/Firefox/Safari should get rounded corners and < IE9 should not.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use tables for layout. For rounded corners in browser that don't support native `border-radius`, you can use graphics corners as background of absolutely-positioned empty elements.